# Nodejs combine request 2 sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an app that store data of multiple users in stormdb for example

User A Login and send some requests and i will log it in his table
And
User B Login and send some requests and i will log it in his table

the issue in here when both send requests the database log user request one for all users

code example

```
var StormDB = require("stormdb");

// start db with "./db.stormdb" storage location
const engine = new StormDB.localFileEngine("./users.stormdb");
const db = new StormDB(engine);

var ddf = JSON.stringify(global.spider).replace("'",'"');
var index = db.get("users").state.users.findIndex((a)=>a.email == useremail);
         
 var kk = db.get("users").get(index).get("spider").set(ddf);
                
    db.save();
```

Comment: You'll have to show some [mcve] code here if you want folks to give you any meaningful  help, because if both users have their own table, two requests cannot write to the same table, irrespective of whether those requests happen concurrently or at different times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an Global variable in your code that works same thing for all users , you need to remove that global variable .